# Quitar todas las imagenes de word de forma recursiva

Tags: vba, vbscript, vbs

Tengo una ruta con multitud de documentos word dentro de subcarpetas.
Estoy intentando mediante un script (VBScript) quitar todas las imagenes que tienen esos ficheros word de la siguiente forma:

```
Dim FileSystem 
Dim HostFolder

HostFolder = "C:\Users\......."

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim fichero
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next

    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        fichero = CStr(File)
        fso.GetExtensionName (fichero)
        If fso.GetExtensionName(fichero) = "doc" Or fso.GetExtensionName(fichero) = "docx" Then
            quitarFoto (fichero)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub quitarFoto(fichero)
    Dim objWord
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    objWord.Documents.Open fichero

    Dim iShp As InlineShape

    For Each iShp In objWord.InlineShapes
        With iShp
            iShp.Delete
        End With
    Next iShp
    objWord.Save
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Pero no consigo que la funcion quitarFoto haga nada y me devuelve el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente, porque las formas están en un objeto 'document':

```
Sub quitarFoto(fichero)
Dim doc as Document
Dim objWord
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open fichero

Dim iShp As InlineShape

For Each iShp In doc.InlineShapes
    With iShp
        iShp.Delete
    End With
Next iShp
objWord.Save
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```